# deploying an angular app on aws cloudfront

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudfront

I have a laravel php app which is basically an api that the user will access through an angular single page app.  Currently the angular app is contained with the public folder but I want to break it off on its own so that I can deploy it via amazon cloudfront.

I found [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html) article for hosting static websites on CloudFront which explains the basics but I cannot find anything that discusses the hitting of an api with your cdn served site.

I would like to still be able to have 3 different environments, dev/staging and production which each currently have their own elastic beanstalk managed instances and seperate databases.  I would like their addresses to be dev.blah.com / staging.blah.com and blah.com respectively and have each version of the angular app hit the correct backend etc.

I would like to be able to deploy the angular app in a similar way to how I deploy to elastic beanstalk, ie git push

Can I set it up so I dont need to modify the api endpoints in the angular app for each environment.  ie the dev version hits dev.blah.com/get/user/1 and with the same source the staging hits staging.blah.com/get/user/1?  Will this happen automatically or do I need to take specific actions to allow for this?

Are all these things possible?  I dont expect a step by step guide but just looking for an outline of the process and a push towards where I can find the resources to learn how to do this myself as my searches have not resulted in much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On CloudFront, in the "behaviors" tab of your distribution, you can assign a path to every origin. For example, you can specify that /* requests are redirected to a S3 bucket with your static resources but /api/* is redirected to your api backend.

As for the dev/staging/prod environments, those would probably be 3 different distributions too. They can point to the same or to different origins.

See "[Whole Site Delivery with CloudFront](http://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/whole-site-delivery-with-amazon-cloudfront)"

Comment: Thanks it actually seems like it might be fairly straightforward from that talk  I will accept your answer but would love to hear from some other people as well if they have anything to add